Can't stop a running instance of a class that uses CrowCpp
EDIT: The original POC had some issues but the issue remains.
I've added a compile time flag should someone want to test.
Code has been updated.
I have a linux application and the last class I've added uses CrowCpp to serve a website that'll become the gui in the end.
When I interrupt the program by pressing CTRL-C the main program loop just keeps on running. I do not have that issue with instances of other classes.
Everything shuts down cleanly but if I dare run the website it no longer works.
I have eventhandlers in place for amongst others SIGHUP and SIGINT. SIGINT is the equivalent of pressing CTRL-C in a terminal.
Both can be sent as kill -SIGHUP pid and kill -SIGINT pid. The latter is thus the equivalent op pressing CTRL-C.
I made a POC that only installs 2 signal handlers that exhibits the same problem. It could be a bit shorter but I kept the main program loop the same as in the real code.
    #include <iostream>
    #include <csignal>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <thread>
    #include <atomic>
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <crow.h> // https://crowcpp.org
    
    std::atomic_bool basicTest = true; // Compile time flag. Set to false to test crow.
    
    std::atomic_bool keepOnRunning = true; // Main program loop control.
    
    class Worker {
    public:
        Worker() : keepOnWorking(true), workerThreadIsRunning(false) {
            std::cout << "Constructing Worker instance." << std::endl;
            processingThread = std::thread(&Worker::doWork, this); // Start webserverThread in a separate thread.
        }
    
        ~Worker() {
            if(basicTest){
                keepOnWorking = false;
            }
            else {
                app.stop();
            }
            if (processingThread.joinable()) {
                processingThread.join();
            }
            std::cout << "Destructed Worker instance." << std::endl;
        }
    
        void doWork() {
            workerThreadIsRunning = true;
            std::cout << "Workerthread starting..." << std::endl;
    
            if(basicTest){
                std::mutex cv_m;
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
                std::condition_variable cv;
                while (keepOnWorking) {
                    cv.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(500), [this] { return !keepOnWorking; });
                    std::cout << "Sign of life from workerthread ..." << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else{
                // Define the endpoint at the root directory
                CROW_ROUTE(app, "/")([](){
                    return "Hello world";
                });
                // Set the port, configure to run on multiple threads, and run the app
                app.signal_add(SIGINT);
                app.signal_add(SIGHUP);
                app.port(10000).multithreaded().run(); // This is a blocking call
            }
            workerThreadIsRunning = false;
            std::cout << "Workerthread stopped ..." << std::endl;
        }
    
    private:
        crow::SimpleApp app;
        std::atomic_bool keepOnWorking;
        std::atomic_bool workerThreadIsRunning;
        std::thread processingThread;
    };
    
    void signalHandler(int signum) {
        std::cout << "Received signal " << signum << " -> Exiting gracefully." << std::endl;
        keepOnRunning = false;
    }
    
    int main() {
        std::cout << "PID " << getpid() << std::endl;
        signal(SIGHUP, signalHandler);
        signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    
        {
            Worker worker;
    
            std::mutex cv_m;
            std::condition_variable cv;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
            while (keepOnRunning) {
                cv.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::seconds(1), [] { return !keepOnRunning; });
                std::cout << "Sign of life from main thread ..." << std::endl;
            }
        }
    
        std::cout << "Ending mainthread ..." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    

The output when sending SIGINT:
    ./sandbox4 
    PID 12069
    Constructing MyCrowApp instance.
    Webserver starting ...
    (2024-06-15 16:59:35) [INFO    ] Crow/master server is running at http://0.0.0.0:10088 using 8 threads
    (2024-06-15 16:59:35) [INFO    ] Call `app.loglevel(crow::LogLevel::Warning)` to hide Info level logs.
    Sign of life ...
    Sign of life ...
    -> Command executed -> kill -SIGINT 12069 ( It wouldn't make a difference if I do CTRL-C )
    (2024-06-15 16:59:50) [INFO    ] Closing IO service 0x73e4f4001fc0
    (2024-06-15 16:59:50) [INFO    ] Closing IO service 0x73e4f4001fc8
    (2024-06-15 16:59:50) [INFO    ] Closing IO service 0x73e4f4001fd0
    (2024-06-15 16:59:50) [INFO    ] Closing IO service 0x73e4f4001fd8
    (2024-06-15 16:59:50) [INFO    ] Closing IO service 0x73e4f4001fe0
    (2024-06-15 16:59:50) [INFO    ] Closing IO service 0x73e4f4001fe8
    (2024-06-15 16:59:50) [INFO    ] Closing IO service 0x73e4f4001ff0
    (2024-06-15 16:59:50) [INFO    ] Closing main IO service (0x73e4f4001078)
    (2024-06-15 16:59:50) [INFO    ] Exiting.
    Webserver stopped ...
    -> The main program loop just continues ...
    Sign of life ...
    Sign of life ...
    -> Command executed ->  kill -9 12069
    Killed

The ouput when sending SIGHUP:
    ./sandbox4 
    PID 12094
    Constructing MyCrowApp instance.
    Webserver starting ...
    (2024-06-15 17:04:18) [INFO    ] Crow/master server is running at http://0.0.0.0:10088 using 8 threads
    (2024-06-15 17:04:18) [INFO    ] Call `app.loglevel(crow::LogLevel::Warning)` to hide Info level logs.
    Sign of life ...
    Sign of life ...
    Sign of life ...
    -> Command executed -> kill -SIGHUP 12094
    Received signal 1 -> Exiting gracefully.

Notice there is no output from Crow nor log messages from myApp's destructor.
I experimented with Crow's run_async() method and tried several approaches but nothing works.
It is as if Crow does something to the signals that interferes with the other code.
I've got 15 classes in it with x instances and everything destructs neatly but not so the Crow class.
I don't have a clue anymore.
If somebody has an idea do elaborate please.

The running threads will also have to observe and make decisions based on keepOnRunning. Side note: You can't always use a std::atomic in a signal handler either. Make sure the type is lock free, and if you can't guarantee it will be on all targets, go all the way back to the stone ages and use sig_atomic_t.
